# How can I run 5 azure micro-service instance in same time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have azure micro-service call **Service A**. This micro service always looking queue call **Queue A**. Then I want to run 5 instance of Service A in same time. Is it possible?

if it is possible then what happens when I'm inserting 5 items to queue at same time ?

Comment: What do you mean by _micro-service_? And what have you tried? What type of queue are you writing to, where you think there would be a multi-writer issue? Please edit your question with more info. Right now, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Actually my requirement is parallel processing using micro-service. can I do it using azure micro-service ?

Comment: If you used an Azure Storage Queue and then hosted a service as a web role or VM, then you can scale up your service to 5 instances and the queue would function as you expect.  It can handle multiple concurrent callers, but I think you should devise a scheme within your logic to protect against repeat processing, if that is a concern

Comment: Nope that's not. My concern is memory. My process is heavily memory conception process. So I want to run one process in one micro-service ?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, rather than placing details in comments. Also, please explain what you mean by _micro-service_.

Comment: Please check on google ""What is azure microservice". Then you can find what I mean by microservice